# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Comments#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use polymorphic associations with comments. When I try to add 'edit' and also 'destroy' in show template, I get the error in the title (just edit for now). How do I add both links to show?

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  ....
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :edit]
  before_filter :load_commentable

def index
  @commentable = load_commentable
  @comments = @commentable.comments
end

def show
end

def edit
  @commentable = load_commentable
end

def new
 @commentable = load_commentable
 @comment = @commentable.comments.new
end

def create
 @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
 @comment.user = current_user

if @comment.save
  redirect_to @comment, notice: "Created."
 else
  render :new
 end
end

def update
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.update(comment_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'It was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end



private

def load_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end

....

end
```

show.html.erb template

```
<%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, @commentable, :comment] %>
```

form

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
....
```

[full trace](http://tny.cz/c6b9ed44)

log

> Processing by CommentsController#show as HTML
>   Parameters: {"post_id"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}
>   Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE
>   "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
>   Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" =
>   ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
>   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =
>   ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
>   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."user_id" =
>   ?  [["user_id", 2]]  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments"
>   WHERE "comments"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
>   Rendered comments/show.html.erb within layouts/application (10.7ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit",
>   :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>#, :id=>nil,
>   :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
>
> ```
> 25:           <div class="thumbsdown"><%= link_to image_tag('othericons/thumbiconDown.PNG', height: '20', width: '20'),
> ```
>
> "#" %>
>       26:           <%= link_to image_tag('othericons/flagicon.PNG', height: '20', width: '18'), "#"
>   %>
>       27:         
>       28: <%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, @commentable, :comment] %>    29:
>       30:     
>       31:                                                                                                                                                                            app/views/comments/show.html.erb:28:in
>   `_app_views_comments_show_html_erb___2937579164590753686_69833853514120'
>
> ```
> Rendered /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb
> ```
>
> (1.6ms)                                              Rendered
>   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb
>   (1.2ms)                               Rendered
>   /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb
>   within rescues/layout (19.1ms)

routes:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Comment: Can you share the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: I added it. What's your opinion?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Also can you add the error message from the server log `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Comments#show`

Comment: I added that as well.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I also need to look at your routes from your `routes.rb`

Comment: Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Added an answer. Try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Edit` Link as below:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_comment_path(@commentable, @comment) %>
```

You have setup Post and Comment as nested routes, so you need to pass objects of Post as well as Comment to the edit path.

**EDIT**

For Polymorphic association, you could use it as below:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, @commentable, @comment] %>
```

Comment: It works for :posts. But, I use polymorphic associations - there are other resources, like :photos that have comments as well.

Comment: @Xantar See my EDIT in the answer.

Comment: Could you also post it for 'destroy' action? How to delete it?

Comment: <%= link_to "Delete", [@commentable, @comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

Comment: See my above comment for Delete.